# How to show that $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}(2 x_n + \frac{a}{x_n^2})$ has an upper bound?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $x_n>0$ and $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}(2 x_n + \frac{a}{x_n^2})$. We need to compute the $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n $.

My solution: suppose that the limit exists. Then we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a^{1/3}$ by taking limits in both sides of $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}(2 x_n + \frac{a}{x_n^2})$. Now we need to show that the limit exists. We have $x_{n+1} - x_n = \frac{1}{3}(-x_n + \frac{a}{x_n^2}) \geq 0$ if  $0 < x_n \leq a^{1/3}$. Therefore we only need to show that $0 < x_n \leq a^{1/3}$. But I have some difficulty in showing that $0 < x_n \leq a^{1/3}$.

How to show that $0 < x_n \leq a^{1/3}$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. By the inequality of the arithmetic and geometric mean
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+x_n+a/x_n^2}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{x_n·x_n·\frac{a}{x_n^2}}=\sqrt[3]a
$$
so that, independent of where you start, the remainder of the iteration is above $\sqrt[3]a$.

---

But by the same identity you already used, you can show that the sequence (excluding the first element) is then decreasing.